# HTMX request trigerring other htmx request

Tags: javascript, htmx

I am trying to code a small chat website based on htmx and flask. This would be a turn-based chat for two users, one sends a message, then needs to wait for the other user to respond before resending a message. uI am aiming to have three components : one div containing the input to send messages, one div containing a waiting message and a final div containg the messages sent.

I trigger my htmx requests with some javascript, would it be fully doable in hx-trigger ? (I am trying to update all divs when the submit button is pressed). In other words, I want to trigger some htmx request when a button is pressed with the less javascript code possible.

```
<div id="all">
    <h1>Chat miaou miaou</h1>

    <div id="ui-form" hx-get="/display_form" hx-swap="innerHTML" hx-trigger="load, every 4s">
<form id='submit_form' hx-post='/submit'><input type='text' name='message' placeholder='Enter message'><button type='submit'>Submit</button></form>
</div>
    <div id="ui-wait" hx-get="/display_wait" hx-swap="innerHTML" hx-trigger="load, every 4s"></div>
    <p>---------------</p>
    <div id="output" hx-get="/messages" hx-swap="innerHTML" hx-trigger="load, every 4s"></div>
</div>
<script>

    document.addEventListener('htmx:afterRequest', function (event) {
    if (event.srcElement["htmx-internal-data"].verb == 'post') {
        // The specific form POST request has completed, now trigger other requests
        document.dispatchEvent(new Event('refresh'));
    }
});

function fetchData(url, target) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        htmx.ajax('GET', url, target)
            .then(() => resolve())
            .catch((error) => reject(error));
    });
};

document.addEventListener('refresh', async function () {
    try {
        await fetchData('/display_form', '#ui-form');
        await fetchData('/display_wait', '#ui-wait');
        await fetchData('/messages', '#output');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in refresh event:', error);
    }
});
</script>
```

So right now, I have this javascript solution but I wondered if there wasn't an easier way to do so.

Comment: Why don't you wrap all divs that you plan to update as result of a HTMX action in one div and make `hx-target` point to this?

Comment: @Windowlicker I think if you wrap both the form and the output in the same div, then you'll lose form content if the output updates.

Answer (score 0):

Although websockets will be ideal for this use case, I still thought it is a nice idea so show that it still possible with HTMX alone. I did it with Django but I think you can borrow the basic idea for Flask.

The flow you need can easily be achieved by triggering HTMX client events at the server.
Here is my setup:

1. When no messages, enable textarea for both users.
2. When user1 sends a message, disable it. user2 had already had it open so can reply.
3. When user2 replies, disable it for them and enable it for user1.

My markup is similar to yours:

```
<div class="container" hx-get="{% url 'chatroom' %}" hx-trigger="every 5s">
  <div id="chats">
    <!-- Messages container -->
  </div>
<!-- Form -->
  <div id="form-wrapper">
    <form hx-target="#chats" hx-on::after-request="this.reset()" hx-post="{% url 'send-message' %}">
        
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
document.body.addEventListener("myTurn", ()=>{
//id_message is the id of the textbox    
document.getElementById("id_message").removeAttribute("disabled")
})
document.body.addEventListener("notMyTurn", ()=>{
    document.getElementById("id_message").setAttribute("disabled", "true")
})
</script>
```

The polling request on the `.container` will simply return all messages sent and update `#chats` div. What function that's return these messages is also checking if the last message sent was by the current user. If that's true, it will trigger an `notMyTurn` event, otherwise `myTurn` event will be triggered. Those are the events the script is listening for on the `body`.

But these events will not work on initial page (as it it is not an HTMX request), so on the initial load (where it's rendering the homepage and the form), I am doing the check and adding `disabled` attribute to the form (I'm using Django's `Model forms`).

Then on form submission, I'm simply resetting the form using the `hx-on` attribute.

Perhaps you can pick a few things from my backend code:

```
def can_user_send_message(user, response): # Simple utility function to set Hx-Trigger header
    response["Hx-Trigger"] = "myTurn"
    if Message.objects.all() and Message.objects.last().user == user:
        response["Hx-Trigger"] = "notMyTurn"
    return response


# Request handlers
class ChatHomeView(generic.View): # Renders the homepage
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = MessageForm()
        messages = Message.objects.all()
        if messages and (messages.last().user == request.user):
            form.fields["message"].widget.attrs["disabled"] = "true"
        return render(request, "core/chat/home.html", locals())

class RoomView(generic.View): # Renders the messages to the #chats div
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        messages = Message.objects.all()
        response = render(request, "core/chat/room.html", locals())
        return can_user_send_message(request.user, response)
        return response
class MessageView(generic.View): # Save submitted message, and renders the room template, and sets updates Hx-trigger header
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Save form
            response = render(request, "core/chat/room.html", dict(messages=Message.objects.all())
            return can_user_send_message(request.user, response)
```

This is how my implementation looks:[image]

**Note:**

To avoid writing any raw JS, I tried to use `hyperscript` for the `myTurn` and `notMyTurn` events, but for some reason it was not picking up the events. For most simple cases, hypescript compliments HTMX quite well.